# What's Pakistan like for a foreigner (a Polish) guy who wants to travel there?

Tags: pakistan, polish-citizens

I'm a Polish guy who wants to travel to the beautiful country of Pakistan. I would appreciate it if someone with experience of that place as a tourist chimes in.

How is it like there?

I mean with regards to safety, security and other things like people understanding English?

I have searched the web but still I thought I'd ask here in case someone has had an experience with that place.

I'm mostly thinking about visiting the province [Punjab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punjab,_Pakistan) and [Sindh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sindh) (in the south).

Comment: your question is opinion based, but short answer things have changed in the last 3 years. Please see [1](https://www.quora.com/How-safe-is-travelling-in-Pakistan), [2](https://www.thebrokebackpacker.com/pakistan-travel-ultimate-backpacker-guide/) and many more you can find on internet. Sindh and Punjab are really cultural province, the real pakistan beauty is in northern areas [Gilgit Baltistan](http://nativepakistan.com/photos-of-gilgit-baltistan/). Have a save journey

Comment: Polish MFA publishes safety updates on Polak za Granicą website (Polish abroad) https://polakzagranica.msz.gov.pl/Islamska,Republika,Pakistanu,PAK.html, current status is "travel discouraged because of terrorism issues". You may know youtube channel "Przez świat na Fazie", guy crossed Pakistan recently but it didn't seem very safe, he also mentioned he was practically the only tourist there. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EE-u2Ns9G0

Comment: This is a great question but unfortunately it's a little too broad for this site.You might want to ask about something more specific like "How common is it to find English speakers in Lahore?"